# How can I use the kernel function in my C code?

Tags: kernel, debian

First, i want to apologize for my English, it's not my mother language but i will do my best.

I'm a new developer in Debian, before that I only do cross-plateform code.
Since cross-plateform isn't in my constraint anymore, I want to be as close as possible from the kernel.

For example, i want to use AES for crypt file. AES exist in the kernel and I prefer to use the AES kernel rather than another AES (I simply trust more the kernel source code). Is there a way to use Kernel function in user space ?
More precisely, does exist a method, or a documentation for that ?

If i want to have the doc of a C function, i do "man function". Is there an equivalent for kernel ?

I hope I doesn't make a mistake with my question.
Thank you for your reading, stack overflow help me a dozen and dozen time in the past, so thank you.

Edit : Sorry, i edit my post and I Hope it's better this time.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please try to make your questions as index-friendly as possible so that they may help others who have the same problems as you in the future. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of the following indexing issues: 1. asking how to get [manuals detailing how to get] source code for a program is not related to the language the program was written in; the C tag shouldn't be here. 2. multiple unrelated questions should be split into multiple questions.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for the precision, i edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to use Kernel function in user space?

No, kernel function cannot be called directly from user space.

You can write kernel module, which calls desired function as responce to some request from user space.